# CSRF error on SecurityComponent when using FormHelper::file

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

CSRF error on SecurityComponent when using FormHelper::file in CakePHP v3.4.14

> Unexpected field 'settings.server.bookings_email_image' in POST data,
>   Missing field 'settings.server.bookings_email_image.name,
>   settings.server.bookings_email_image.type,
>   settings.server.bookings_email_image.tmp_name,
>   settings.server.bookings_email_image.error,
>   settings.server.bookings_email_image.size' in POST data

Code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null,['id'=>'publisher-form']) ?>
echo $this->Form->file("settings.$domain.$id", [
    'label' => $setting->label  . ($setting->required === true ? ' (Required)' : '' ),
]);
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Workaround:

```
$this->Form->unlockField("settings.$domain.$id");
$this->Form->unlockField("settings.$domain.$id.name");
$this->Form->unlockField("settings.$domain.$id.type");
$this->Form->unlockField("settings.$domain.$id.tmp_name");
$this->Form->unlockField("settings.$domain.$id.error");
$this->Form->unlockField("settings.$domain.$id.size");
```

It seems silly that I would have to unlock this field. Is there something special you need to do when dealing with files?

Comment: Please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks! Without seeing the rest of your form code, I would suspect that you're possibly not using the correct type, hence the secured default file upload fields are missing.

Comment: Updated question, its CakePHP v3.4.14. The Form is huge and split amongst several elements as part of a "create wizard" so it doesn't make sense to post it all. What do you mean not using the correct type? I'll add what I can to the main question. Whomever downvoted this is a douche.

Comment: I was referring to the `type` option of the `FormHelper::create()` call, [**it needs to be set to `file`**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-file-inputs) in order for files to be sent properly.

Comment: You're absolutely right.